# Compressing png images using PHP

Tags: php, image, image-compression

I'm looking for a PNG compression algorithm/library in PHP that is similar to: https://tinypng.com/

It's compression is by the best
Any ideas out there on ones to check out? Google didn't net too many good results.

Comment: You could use `pngout` if your host supports `exec` http://advsys.net/ken/utils.htm

Comment: any more details on pngout?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use this and it works wonders.

http://pngquant.org/php.html

Comment: im testing it now. i got a sample image down to 4k, but tinypng.com is still able to get it down to 2.4. they're actually using pngquant, so they must be chaining it with another compression or something

Comment: worked awesome for me